# Failed to connect to and describe Kafka cluster In Standalone mode

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have installed zookeeper and kafka,zookeeper is ruuning fine but as per my requirement I want to run Kafka-connect standalone to connect kafka and cassandsra. I am using following command to start kafka server `kafka/bin/connect-standalone.sh kafka/config/connect-standalone.properties kafka-connect-cassandra-sink-1.4.0/conf/cassandra-sink-standalone.properties` . The connect-standalone.properties configuration file is given below:

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter.schemas.enable=true

offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000

plugin.path=/home/shamama/kafka-connect-cassandra-sink-1.4.0/kafka-connect-cassandra-sink-1.4.0.jar

############################# Zookeeper #############################

# Zookeeper connection string (see zookeeper docs for details).
# This is a comma separated host:port pairs, each corresponding to a zk
# server. e.g. "127.0.0.1:3000,127.0.0.1:3001,127.0.0.1:3002".
# You can also append an optional chroot string to the urls to specify the
# root directory for all kafka znodes.
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181

# Timeout in ms for connecting to zookeeper
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=18000


listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
#advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
```

The following error is occurring after starting kafka standalone server:

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to connect to and describe Kafka cluster. Check worker's broker connection and security properties.
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConnectUtils.lookupKafkaClusterId(ConnectUtils.java:70)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConnectUtils.lookupKafkaClusterId(ConnectUtils.java:51)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:82)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=listNodes, deadlineMs=1628583433705, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=1628583433806) timed out at 1628583433706 after 1 attempt(s)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow(KafkaFutureImpl.java:45)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.access$000(KafkaFutureImpl.java:32)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:260)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConnectUtils.lookupKafkaClusterId(ConnectUtils.java:64)
```

I cannot figure out my mistake.Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates Kafka isn't running.

Based on your previous question, you're running `kafka-server-start` with the wrong property file

Specifically, `zookeeper.connect`, `listeners`, and `advertised.listeners` should not be part of `connect-standalone.properties`, and you need `broker.id`, at a minimum, to start a broker (already part of `server.properties`)

Comment: I have updated my standalone.properties configurations as you suggested and then started kafka `server.properties` first and then started `standalone.properties` and now they both are sink and working. thanks